# Frequency array feeds FFT

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency

The final goal I am trying to achieve is the generation of a ten minutes time series: to achieve this I have to perform an `FFT` operation, and it's the point I have been stumbling upon.

Generally the aimed time series will be assigned as the sum of two terms: a steady component `U(t)` and a fluctuating component `u'(t)`. That is

```
u(t) = U(t) + u'(t);
```

So generally, my code follows this procedure:

**1) Given data**

```
time = 600 [s];

Nfft = 4096;

L = 340.2 [m];

U = 10 [m/s];

df = 1/600 = 0.00167 Hz;

fn = Nfft/(2*time) = 3.4133 Hz;
```

This means that my frequency array should be laid out as follows:

```
f = (-fn+df):df:fn;
```

But, instead of using the whole `f` array, I am only making use of the positive half:

```
fpos = df:fn = 0.00167:3.4133 Hz;
```

**2) Spectrum Definition**

I define a certain spectrum shape, applying the following relationship

```
Su = (6*L*U)./((1 + 6.*fpos.*(L/U)).^(5/3));
```

**3) Random phase generation**

I, then, have to generate a set of `complex` samples with a determined distribution: in my case, the random phase will approach a standard Gaussian distribution (`mu = 0, sigma = 1`).

In `MATLAB` I call

```
nn = complex(normrnd(0,1,Nfft/2),normrnd(0,1,Nfft/2));
```

**4) Apply random phase**

To apply the random phase, I just do this

```
Hu = Su*nn;
```

At this point start my pains!

So far, I only generated `Nfft/2 = 2048` complex samples accounting for the `fpos` content. Therefore, the content accounting for the negative half of `f` is still missing. To overcome this issue, I was thinking to merge the **real** and **imaginary** part of `Hu`, in order to get a signal `Huu` with `Nfft = 4096` samples and with all real values.

But, by using this merging process, the **0-th** frequency order would not be represented, since the **imaginary** part of `Hu` is defined for `fpos`.

Thus, how to account for the **0-th** order by keeping a procedure as the one I have been proposing so far?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding correctly, but assuming the ultimate aim is to `ifft` the data, why don't you just use the `'symmetric'` option?

Comment: The way you "randomize" phases is also randomizing amplitudes.  A random phase vector will be something like `exp(i*normrnd(0,2*pi,Nfft/2))`.

Comment: @natan: adjusting the randomization process, would it be possible to overcome my problem? Btw, I suspect that using your random generation, after merging imaginary and real part, the FFT will retrieve a periodic time series with period 300s.